# Why use <script> part of Google Conversion Script when there is the <noscript> part?

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api

Here's my situation:

I'd like to use Google AdWord's conversion script, but for some reason the javascript part of their snippet adds some undesirable whitespace to my page that I can't seem to get rid of.

So the option I'm looking at is purely using the  part of their snippet where the 1x1 image is loaded. Obviously I would take out the  tags to make that 1x1 image appear all the time for all browsers, and I'll remove the  part of their snippet.

My question is, is there a disadvantage to this? There must be a reason why Google's conversion script has a javascript and non-javascript option. Is the javascript option better somehow than the non-javascript option? If they are equally good, then why didn't Google just keep it simple and use the non-javascript method for all browsers, regardless of whether they have javascript or not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not particularly familiar with AdWords, but in general, most website analytics tools have both options, and the JavaScript option is better because it can provide more details about the user.

The `noscript` option, by loading a 1x1 image, simply logs a request on the server-side, and this contains very limited information such as your IP address and your browser's user agent string.

Using JavaScript can give you additional information such as display resolution, referring page and whether plug-ins such as Flash/Java are installed.

Comment: Thanks I think this answers my question.

Comment: FWIW, I recently noticed that the tracking pixel injects an iframe (which is then removed after the conversion), so I would bet that you're not losing out on much, if any data by using the pixel, assuming you have a DOM. I've also tried just requesting the pixel, and it doesn't seem to fire the conversion, so I think you may need a DOM to work with the pixel (or the script).

Comment: @Jesse: Injecting into the DOM would still require JavaScript to be enabled. The question could possibly be seen as "why use JavaScript for tracking when there is a noscript option".

Comment: True, but it appears that you can just use the pixel, regardless of js is available or not. The script & pixel seem to do exactly the same thing when you have js, although I could be wrong.